# Why do people working at the airport need to know what the purpose of the tourists' trips are?

Tags: tourist-traps

What is the purpose of completing your travel slip when on the plane?

Comment: By "travel slip", are you referring to the immigration forms passed out on the plane before landing?

Comment: Isn't it for the customs official when you get to the destination country? Customs would understandably want to know what you're doing there, because people might want to smuggle things, no?

Comment: @Yehuda more fundamentally, many countries process arriving passengers differently depending on the purpose of their travel, often because the conditions of entry depend on that.  For example, someone might be able to enter without a visa for up to six months if the purpose is tourism, but if the purpose is study a visa might be required.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of people at the airport do not need to know. A small number (1 to 3, typically) do. These people work in Immigration, deciding whether to let you in or not, or in Customs, deciding how thoroughly to search your possessions as part of deciding whether to let them in or not, or in a joint Customs and Immigration role deciding both things. That's who the "travel slip" is for. Most travelers only meet one person for this decision process, but a small number are sent to talk to more people for a final decision.

Some other people at the airport may ask to see your form, mostly to make sure that you have filled it out before you get to the front of the line where the people need to see it. In addition, some other people may ask you, typically before you get on the plane, to show your passport and (if needed) a visa. These people work for the airline and want to be sure they don't transport someone who won't be let in, since they might incur costs as a result of that mistake. Since many countries offer different tourist and business visas, these people may ask you about the purpose of your trip too.

Comment: And some may just be trying to be friendly.

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons.

**Airlines** and travel booking companies ask it, for segmentation (different price for different people), marketing purposes, and also to help "their algorithm" to better predict passengers travelling (and better estimate the "overbooking").

**Custom, police, immigration**. It is just a question, it helps to see how people behave and also to select next question. Easy question are easy discriminant (and get a first feeling).

**immigration, airlines**: also to check if your visa is valid. Airlines get often (depending on the country) a fine if transport you with a non-valid visa.

**Other passengers and personal (e.g. restaurant, shops)**: just to be nice and start conversion.